# Can you put an area of a residence in selection?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

If you create a residence (using [this bukkit mod](http://residencebukkitmod.wikispaces.com)) you may need to enlarge it later on. Unfortunately, I see no way to put an area of residence in residence selection - so that I expand it.

This is what I imagine:

```
/res select resarea Home
```

This would select the area of the existing residence - this command is what I need, but can't find.

```
/res select expand 5
```

Expand selected area by 5 units/by a factor of 5.

```
/res area replace Home main
```

Replace the old area with the new expanded one.

Comment: What about `/res area`? According to the wiki: *`/res area [add/remove/replace] <residence> [areaID]` - Add or remove areas to the residence. These can overlap with areas of the same residence.*

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a limit of 2 areas per residence. This is because the areas are not simply concatenated with the old area, but created as new objects.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://betteringame.com/page/articles.html/_/mcarticles/how-to-expand-an-existing-residence-r10) is a useful guide to expand a residence:

> The first step to expanding an existing residence is to select the entire residence into our selection “clipboard.”
>
> Every residence has at least one area. By default, that area is called “main” and occupies the entire residence. To select the entire residence, you need to select that area. Replace the word YourResName with the name of the residence you wish to expand.
>
> `/res select residence YourResName main`

In your case you would use:

```
/res select residence Home main
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of actually changing/expanding the current residence, you could try to select and construct a new residence with the wooden axe. Then you can remove the original residence (Home).

That way you don't have to figure out how to change the current residence.